# What is Try-Catch Really Catching

Tags: javascript, try-catch

What does Try-Catch really catches? In which scenarios catch will be triggered?

if given request:

```
try { 
   const response = await axios.get('someURL/api/apiEndpoint')
   ...(do something with response)
} catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
    ...(Do something with error)
}
```

And Backend Code:

```
 app.get('/api/apiEndpoint', (req, res, next) => {
     const notLoggedIn = () => {
         return res.status(200).send({
             error: 'Not logged in'
         })
     }
 })
```

Will that try-catch block catch that there is an error?

Comment: No it's based on response status, if you send error response status code like 503, 404, 400 then it will go inside catch block

Comment: Try..catch will catch fail of axios promise that probably will happen if you return 500 error (or any non 200 response) from backend. If you have only 200 response you don't need try..catch but it's good ot have it just in case you later add errors on backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will go in catch block only if response has error status code like 503 (internal server error), 400 (bad request)

In your case you're sending 200 status code, so it will not go inside catch

For more information about status codes check - https://httpstatuses.com/